# Defer Anniversary Upgrade in Windows 10 Home without Metered Connection hack

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, windows-10-v1607

I have a laptop with Windows 10 Home 1511. It uses an external device for which the driver is not compatible with the new 1607 ("Anniversary Upgrade") version yet. The device manufacturer explicitly recommended not upgrading to 1607 while they are working on a new driver.

The [only solution I could find](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-delay-windows-10-anniversary-update) suggests setting the `metered connection` option for the Wi-Fi/Ethernet connection as a way to stop Windows from downloading the upgrade. This is not satisfying for my case because it turns out you can travel around with a laptop and connect to many different Wi-Fis, and it's very tedious to always set them up as metered connections.

Is there a better approach?

Here are some ideas, in order of decreasing desirability:

- Tell Windows to defer the upgrade through some hidden setting or additional tool.
- Automatically set all network connections as metered.
- Install the upgrade and roll it back. This seems to be possible, but I don't know if it will prevent the upgrade from being installed again.

Comment: I assume you have verified the device actually is not compatible with Version 1607?  It seems odd that a device wouldn't work for Version 1607, the only reason I can think of, is it used something very specific which happened to be discontinued.  Happened with some application that used specific Win32 calls.

Comment: I haven't verified, but got an email from the vendor warning about the upgrade, and I have no reason to think they are lying about the incompatibility. The device is a camera for a microscope which is presumably not sold to the masses and does not have dozens of developers working on the device driver...

Comment: This a device you can connect to a VM, simplest way, you can verify problems actually exist.